# How to programmatically draw smooth stroke around a button in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-layout, paint

I am trying to draw a smoothed antialiased stroke around a gradient-filled button but the corners gets really ugly. This is my code:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape;

public class StrokeShapeDrawable extends ShapeDrawable {
    Paint fillpaint;
    Paint strokepaint;
    private static final int WIDTH = 1;

    public StrokeShapeDrawable(Shape s) {
        super(s);
        fillpaint = this.getPaint();
        strokepaint = new Paint(fillpaint);
        strokepaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        strokepaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        strokepaint.setStrokeWidth(WIDTH);
        strokepaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Shape shape, Canvas canvas, Paint fillpaint) {
        shape.draw(canvas, fillpaint);
        shape.draw(canvas, strokepaint);
    }

    public void setFillColour(int c) {
        fillpaint.setColor(c);
    }
}
```

And the button creation:

```
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, mLoginBtn.getHeight(),
                new int[] { 
                    0xfff6f6f6, 
                    0xffd2d3d5, 
                    0xffc0c1c4, 
                    0xffc0c1c4},
                new float[] {
                    0, 0.45f, 0.55f, 1 },
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
             return lg;
        }
    };

    float[] roundedCorner = new float[] {15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15};
    StrokeShapeDrawable b = new StrokeShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorner, null, null));
    b.setShaderFactory(sf);
    mLoginBtn.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable)b);
```

My button looks like this:

[image: Button]

Not very nice, anyone has any ideas?

Also I do not want to use a XML file since I am not sure it's possible to achieve two gradients with 50 precent each of the button without using dp's to specify gradient position (since I want to have 50-50 gradients).

Thanks!

Comment: I just wonder why don't you use nine-patch?

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as an overly complex way to achieve something relatively simple. I would have used a [nine-patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) instead - they are perfect for your task.

Comment: I agree but the problem with those are that if I add large text font on the buttons they will be "capped" if the character is for example 'g' (i.e. capped below the base line of the font if it's on the same "level" as the "non-stretchable" area in the nine patch image). I guess this is due to how the nine patch drawables works.

Comment: Not sure I agree with you. Maybe you could post an example?

An alternative to the Button class is to create a StateListDrawable with ImageViews, and set the 9-patch as backgrounds. If I understand you correctly I guess that should work

Comment: I actually ended up doing nine patch anyway as I had 5dp         <item name="android:layout_margin">5sp</item> which cut off the text for me... thanks :-) Nevertheless it would be nice to have an answer on my stroke painting just because I'm curious.